# Import data from directory and text documents in PHP

Tags: php, scandir

I want to push data to array from text documents in a directory where column heading name is ATMP. In each document ATMP position can be changed.

This is the text document how it looks like

```
WDIR WSPD GST WVHT  DPD   APD   MWD  PRES    ATMP  WTMP  DEWP VIS  TIDE
degT m/s  m/s m     sec   sec   degT hPa     degC  degC  degC mi   ft
116  2.8  3.0 99.00 99.00 99.00 999  9999.0  23.8  999.0 16.2 99.0 99.00
117  2.8  3.0 99.00 99.00 99.00 999  9999.0  23.8  999.0 16.2 99.0 99.00
```

This is the code I am trying to achieve it
I will just hit "index.php ATMP" command in my php terminal to make it run

here is the code:

```
$dir  = './files';
$files1 =  preg_grep('/^([^.])/', scandir($dir));
for($x = 0; $x <= count($files1); $x++){
$f1 = fopen($dir . '/' .$files1[$x], 'r');    //
fseek($f1, 0, SEEK_SET);
while(($line =  fgets($f1)) !== false){
array_push($data_array_list, $line);
}
}
```

here 2 things I have to do
1. I have to ignore first two rows before pushing data to array
2. I have to get the below values of ATMP

I am not getting how to solve it. Can you please help me how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have write script to get your desired data. (this script will work when ATMP column change there location)

Remove extra code (for testing purpose. also you can optimize this code)

```
<?php
$myFile = "t1.txt";
$lines = file($myFile);//file in to an array

//var_dump($lines);
echo "<pre>";
$top_row=$lines[0];

$top_row = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ',$top_row);//remove duplicate spaces in lines

$position_data = explode(' ', $top_row);
foreach ($position_data as $key => $value) {
    if($value=='ATMP'){
        $index=$key;//here is your index or column number where ATMP exist
    }
}
print_r($position_data);
unset($lines[0]);
unset($lines[1]); // we do not need these lines.
// exit;
foreach($lines as $key => $line) 
{
    $line = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ',$line);//remove only duplicate or multiple spaces
    $var = explode(' ', $line);
    foreach ($var as $key => $value2) {
        if($index == $key){
            $arr[]=$value2;
        }
    }

    // print_r($key);
    // echo "<br>";
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($arr);
```